# file with html extension not displayed by webkit webview

Tags: python, html, c++, webkit

I'm building an app in C++ to view epub files. Most of the time it works, but with some epubs, the main content files have an extension of .html. When it is asked to open them, webview just gives a blank page. If I do no more than rename the file to have the extension .xhtml, the file is opened and displayed correctly.

Is there any way to tell webview that the file contains xhtml despite its .html extension? If so, the app would no longer have trouble with these epubs, which, incidentally, pass the tests of epubcheck.

If it matters, I have the same problem with the python bindings to webview.

Comment: When I see a file ending with `.html`, I expect to see an ordinary HTML page, not some epub file.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik epubs are basically zip files containing html documents, the op is extracting these files and trying to display them